# ORA-00904 Trying to merge two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

Trying to merge 2 tables. Having issues merging them
If NAME_CINTAS_ column from Locker_audit table is the same as NAME from Locker_Term_List Table, I want the column 'Term_Employee' to update to a value of 'yes' in the Locker Audit table

```
    merge into locker_audit a
    using locker_term_list b
    on (a.name_cintas_ = b.name)
    when matched then update set
         a.term_employee = 'yes';
```

I receive this error

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Error at line 3/13: ORA-00904: "A"."NAME_CINTAS_": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 847
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 833
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1903

1.         merge into locker_audit a
2.         using locker_term_list b
3.         on (a.name_cintas_ = b.name)
4.         when matched then update set
5.              a.term_employee = 'yes';
```

if I try adding the word as I get a different error:

```
    merge into locker_audit as a
    using locker_term_list as b
    on (a.name_cintas_ = b.name)
    when matched then update set
        a.term_employee = 'yes';
```

[image]

Comment: The second error is because Oracle doesn't let you use `AS` for table (or table expression) aliases. For the first error it would be helpful to include both table definitions. (And please post those and the errors as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: I tried and was getting errors for the post. I will update now.